# What's going on with the lawsuit against Concord Management?

Tags: united-states, law, russian-federation

Last year (2018), the US federal government indicted Concord Management & Consulting LLC in relation to the alleged Russian social media campaign to meddle/undermine/influence the 2016 US elections.

The federal government got some egg on its face a few times in this case, e.g. even in the facing of the indictment; and then with wide-reaching discovery requests which the government resits; and also with the government/AG Barr being [found in contempt](https://www.lawfareblog.com/government-violated-dc-local-rule-concord-management-case-court-finds) IIUC, for making extra-judicial statements regarding the defendant's guilt, which they weren't allowed to. So, this has not been such a great experience, PR-wise; and it is not surprising it doesn't get a lot of coverage - especially after the anti-climactic report by Robert Mueller.

My question is: What's actually happening with that case? It's supposedly still being tried, but in what direction is it going? Which side do the evidence, or lack thereof, seem to favor so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concord Management & Consulting LLC has [plead not guilty](https://www.cnn.com/2019/08/20/politics/concord-management-and-consulting-trial/index.html) to the charges and the most recent news I've been been able to find is that, as of September 16th 2019, after many delays related in part to fights over access to sensitive case information, the trial has been scheduled for April 2020:

> A federal judge on Monday pressed lawyers to prepare for an April trial in the prosecution of a Russian company charged with interfering in the 2016 presidential election, expressing frustration over delays in a case that was originally brought by former Special Counsel Robert Mueller III’s office.
>
> “We’re now on a trial track,” declared U.S. District Judge Dabney Friedrich of the District of Columbia
>
> From the bench on Monday, Friedrich denied Dubelier’s bid to extract further information from prosecutors about their case against Concord Management. “Put simply,” Friedrich said, “Concord has what it needs” to prepare for trial.
>
> [‘We’re Now on a Trial Track.’ Judge Pushes End-Game in Russian ‘Troll Farm’ Case](https://www.law.com/nationallawjournal/2019/09/16/were-now-on-a-trial-track-judge-pushes-end-game-in-russian-troll-farm-case/?slreturn=20191105190040)

Since the trial hasn't started yet, there's no way to say which way it's going. Concord has failed in their efforts to get the case dismissed, but aside from that, there's really no objective way to predict if they'll ultimately be found guilty or not.

Comment: You can follow the pre-trial proceedings on [CourtListener](https://www.courtlistener.com/docket/6386795/united-states-v-internet-research-agency-llc/?filed_after=&filed_before=&entry_gte=&entry_lte=&order_by=desc). I've been trying to follow it, but I couldn't describe in 100 words what exactly the crime is.

Comment: @KeithMcClary Thanks for the link! The best I can do is that they are accused of funding an online troll farm to influence the 2016 election

Comment: Also this [blogiating](https://www.emptywheel.net/2019/12/05/doj-flips-the-lawfare-on-its-head-in-russian-troll-case/) from foaming-at-the-mouth Russophobe "emptywheel".